# How to set up apache user and group to current?

Tags: apache2, php

When i trying to install some `CMS` it couldn't create config files because `apache` user is different. On `OS X` i solved this problem by adding user and group in`apache2.conf`, but on Ubuntu i can't figure out what group i should add.

Comment: the group is named `www-data`.

Comment: What Salem said.  But, the full error message is useful you know.  What's the exact error message you are getting?

Comment: @TheLordofTime no errors is provided. I just want to change current group to my users

Answer (score 2):

In Ubuntu and Debian, the user Apache runs as by default is `www-data:www-data`.  You should not change this so that it runs as a normal user, www-data is a special system account.

Comment: i know, but i need to change it to the current user.

Comment: @Kirix Why not just have your folders you have the files in group owned by `www-data` such that it shows as `user:www-data`, thereby giving www-data read/write as is needed?  It's not a good idea to have a web server running as non `www-data` for most deployments.

Comment: You should not run the apache2 under the user which can modify the scripts.  It's much better just to allow the CMS to write it's config file, f.e. by creating config file or config directory and setting the ownership to that file just for the moment of config file creation.

Comment: True, that is also acceptable.